# Resolve hostnames via socks5 globally?

Tags: proxy

I'm trying to configure a "global" socks5 name resolution setting so that when I run `ping google.com` it actually tries to resolve google.com via the socks proxy.

For example, to get curl to do this, I would just type in `curl --socks5-hostname 127.0.0.1:9050 https://www.google.com`, but this is *only* for curl.

Another example:

```
root@server:~/proxychains-ng-4.16 # ./proxychains4 -q curl https://ssm.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
<UnknownOperationException/>

root@server:~/proxychains-ng-4.16 # curl https://ssm.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ssm.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
```

Is there a way to somehow set this globally in a RHEL environment?

Comment: I think no: ping (along with lots of other tools) use `libresolv` which only consults `resolv.conf` (and other systems, see `nsswitch.conf`) but not socks. Ping even can't use socks (socks if for UDP and TCP only, not ICMP). See :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274934/use-ping-through-socks-server

Comment: Thanks. I understand, but I think what I'm looking to find out is if there's some sort of global setting for this. It doesn't have to be ping necessarily, but just any tool - curl, telnet, netcat, etc. I think the referenced article is specifically related to ping and checking the health of the proxyserver. instead of routing all DNS via socks proxy